# Add dynamically rows when user click on button?

Tags: javascript, html

Add dynamically rows when user click on button. I made a script but it does not work plz help me out

```html
   
<script>
var t;
t=2;
function Insert(){
var tab=document.getElementById("mytable");

var row=insertRow(t);
var cell1=insertCell(0);
var cell2=insertCell(1);
var cell3=insertCell(2);
var cell4=insertCell(3);
 
t=t+1;
 
 
   cell2.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');
   cell3.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');
   cell4.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');
}
</script>
Html 
<input type="button"  onclick="Insert()" name="Insert Row" value="Insert Row" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your script like

```html
<script>
var t;
t=2;
function Insert(){
var tab=document.getElementById("mytable");

var row=tab.insertRow(t);
var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
 
t=t+1;
 
 
   cell2.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');
   cell3.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');
   cell4.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');
}
</script>
```

Comment: insertRow and insertCell are [Object methods](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp), in your script you use them as [functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp). Object methods, as the name tells you; require an object in order to be called. This is done with the ' . ' which is a property accessor.

Comment: you get table id and store that in tab variable now you inserting the row without mention table so where it will enter the row

Comment: done thank you so much please refer me some good book for java script

Answer (score 2):

```js
function addRow(tableID) {

   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);


   var cell3 = row.insertCell(0);
   var element2 = document.createElement("input");
   element2.type = "text";
   element2.name = "txtbox[]";
   cell3.appendChild(element2);


  }
```

```html
<BODY>

 <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />


 <TABLE id="dataTable" width="100px" border="1">
  <TR>
   <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
  </TR>
 </TABLE>

</BODY>
```

Comment: done thank you so much please refer me some good book for java script

Comment: You can download pdf from tutorialspoint.com, you can learn from that site